# IQ, Intelligence and Critical Thinking

Tags: iq

I consider myself to be a very critical and analytical thinker. I can't help obsess over every little detail, consider various perspectives, use-cases, etc. I've been programming since a young age (self-taught). At the same time, I have ADHD and a bad working memory.

If I master something, I find that I can think critically and outside the box much better than someone else. I can utilise it better, build upon it better, etc.

Because of my bad short term memory, I assume i will do generally bad in IQ tests and this is not surprising.

Because of my bad memory, it might take me longer to master something than someone else.

Do IQ tests measure critical thinking ability at all? Or just working memory? IQ and working memory are highly correlated.

Comment: People with ADHD tend to have lower IQ test scores, possibly not because of bad working memory, but because distractions consumes most of it. Also, maybe these disrtactions facilitate creativity.

Answer (score 2):

There are a variety of "IQ" tests which attempt to achieve a particular goal (culture-fairness, isolating specialized aspects of cognition, etc.).

"Raven's Progressive Matrices" is a popular type of test that was originally developed in search of an IQ-metric that was "culture-fair" (that is, scoring well did not rely on any cultural background).

In the same vein, it's possible to find specialized IQ tests which selectively measure verbal reasoning, spatial reasoning, and/or memory in isolation. The following website is a battle-tested resource for these sorts of metrics:
https://www.cambridgebrainsciences.com/

The results can be mapped back into "IQ" space by matching the percentiles (conveniently, with the aid of this table: https://www.iqcomparisonsite.com/iqtable.aspx ).